# c++ void as parameter like PHP

Tags: php, c++

in PHP you can create a function as a parameter for an another function.

Example :

```
function example($stackoverflow) {
    $stackoverflow();
}

example(function() {
    echo "Hi StackOverflow !";
}
```

I would like to do this in C++

```
void Window::clear()
{
    EnumChildWindows(g_hWnd, {}, NULL);
}
```

Comment: In c++ you can't handle functions as an input. You can though create a new function and input it's return value into your `example` function.

Comment: [Here's a list of good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282), plenty of them should have the information you need.

Comment: read about <functional>

Comment: You seem to be looking for [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: I reverted your edit. It is not much fun aiming for a moving target.

Comment: Why remove thanks and WinAPI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do this in C++
Create a new function instead.

Answer (score 4):

The corresponding functionality in C++ is available through function objects [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function):

```
void call(function<void()> f) {
    f();
}
```

The argument that you pass could be a named function, e.g.

```
void test() {
    cout << "test" << endl;
}
...
call(test);
```

or a [*lambda*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7627098/335858) function, e.g.

```
call([]() { cout << "lambda" << endl; });
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/9H7Hx1)

> I would like to do this in C++ with a function from the WinAPI.

Another way of passing a function is with function pointers, which is the approach used by WinAPI. You cannot do it inline, because the API does not take `std::function`, so you have to declare a named function for use in the call:

```
BOOL CALLBACK CheckWindow(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) {
    ... // Your processing code goes here
    return TRUE;
}
...
EnumChildWindows(g_hWnd, CheckWindow, NULL);
```

Comment: Thank you, you just help me for another problem, I edited the post. :D

Answer (score 3):

A pointer to function?

```
void func(void (*another_func)(void))
{
    another_func();
}

void func2(void)
{
    cout << "Hi StackOverflow!" << endl;
}

func(func2);
```

Comment: Thank you, this work well for my another problem ! I edited the post !

Answer (score 1):

Besides passing (named) functions or (unnamed) lambdas as shown by Keine Lust and dasblinkenlight, in the realm of object orientation, you probably should revisit your code design.
Usually, in OOP, function pointers are often obsolete and replaced by a design based on inheritance and function overriding. See the following short program indicating what that could mean:

```
struct Printable {
    virtual void print() const = 0;

};

struct ObjType1 : Printable {
    void print() const override { cout << "Hello SO!" << endl; }
};

struct ObjType2 : Printable {
    void print() const override { cout << "Hello object orientation!" << endl; }
};

void callPrint(Printable &p) {
    p.print();
}

int main() {

    ObjType1 objT1;
    ObjType2 objT2;

    callPrint(objT1);
    callPrint(objT2);
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, thank you ! Is it possible to declare function inside callPrint, Like PHP ?

Answer (score 0):

A pure object-oriented solution, might be useful to keep your code clear and cross-platform, inspired by Java's interface:

```
//Define an C++ interface
class MyInterface 
{
public:
    virtual void func2(void) = 0;
}
//-------------------------------
//Define the function with parameter as interface
void func(MyInterface * pImplementation)
{
    pImplementation->func2();   //Call interface function
}

//-------------------------------
class MyImplementation : public MyInterface
{
public:
    printf("Do something ...\n");
} myImpl;

func(&myImpl);  //Call function with interface implementation
```